# Core data fetching managed object from context doesn't update the value instead inserts into a context why?

Tags: swift, core-data, sql-update, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two context one is Main and other is private. I am using this private context  for all the background  opertaions. I'm making an API call using almofire and object mapper to map objects  so the mapped objects is itself inherits managed object which is created in private context.

Now in the closure success from the api response I get the manged object as the success repsonse. 
When I save this managed object it gets inserted to the coredata. But when I call API for the second time the response gets added as another item I want to overwrite it Instead of updating basically

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Sure I will update the question with code. Give me some time